# Sprade distinct values over a different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, distinct

I'm using SQL Server. I have the following table (`MyTable`):

```
ID (int)
value (varchar)
```

I have the following query:

```
select distinct value
from MyTable
```

And the output is:

```
Value_1
Value_2
Value_3
...
...
...
Value_450
```

I would like to crate the following table (when value = 'value_1' then 1 else o...):

```
ID | Value_1 | Value_2 | Value_3 | Value_4 | .... | Value_450
1  |   0     |    1    |    0    |   0     | .... |   0
2  |   0     |    0    |    0    |   1     | .... |   0
3  |   1     |    0    |    0    |   0     | .... |   0
4  |   0     |    1    |    0    |   0     | .... |   0
5  |   0     |    0    |    0    |   0     | .... |   1
6  |   1     |    0    |    0    |   0     | .... |   0
7  |   0     |    0    |    0    |   1     | .... |   0
8  |   0     |    0    |    0    |   0     | .... |   1
```

If the distinct values of `value` was small, I would use `Case` statement for such as query. What should I do in this case which I have so many values? Any smart way to do so?

Comment: What RDBMS you are using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: Look up PIVOT, but I'd question the usefulness of having 450 columns!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with dynamic sql

```
declare @query varchar(max);
declare @values varchar(max) = null;

with distinctValues as
(
    select distinct cast(value as varchar(20)) as value from myTable
)
select @values = COALESCE(@values + ', ['+ value + ']', '['+ value + ']') 
from distinctValues;

set @query = 'select [id], ' + @values +
'from myTable pivot ( count(value) for value in (' + @values + ')) as pvt';

exec(@query);
```

To answer your other questions from the comments:

You can insert the result of a dynamic query into a table by using `INSERT ... EXEC` syntax:

```
insert into myOtherTable 
/* specify columns here if result does not have the same structure as the table */
exec(@query);
```

You said that you have multiple (6) columns that have the same role as the `value` column in your example. I assume that the names of the columns are known and do not vary. So the table structure is:

```
id, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6
```

From what I understand the result must look like this:

```
id, v1, v2, v3, ..., vn
```

where `v1, v2, v3, ..., vn` are all the distinct values that can be found on columns `value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6`

In this case you must use an `UNPIVOT` first:

```
declare @query varchar(max);
declare @values varchar(max) = null;

with distinctValues as
(
    select distinct cast(value as varchar(20)) as value 
    from myTable
    UNPIVOT
    (
       value for col in (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6)
    ) as upvt
)
select @values = COALESCE(@values + ', ['+ value + ']', '['+ value + ']') 
from distinctValues;



set @query = 
';with myTableUnpivoted as 
( 
   select id, value 
   from myTable 
   UNPIVOT 
   ( 
      value for col in (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6) 
   ) as upvt 
) 
select [id], ' + @values +
'from myTableUnpivoted pivot ( count(value) for value in (' + @values + ')) as pvt';

-- insert into myOtherTable
exec(@query);
```

Notice that the the UNPIVOT operation is done twice.

You can store the unpivoted table in a temporary table. Check whether this will improve the performance.

Comment: WOW, man. Amazing solution. I've just checked it and it's works great! Thanks! Actually i need to run this query on a 6 different columns (Value column is a 6 different columns. Each columns has his own distinct values). Is it possible to use your query for a 6 different columns in one time?

Comment: You have to explain better (maybe with another example) what is your table structure and what is the expected result.

Comment: It's the same structure and the same expected result as in my original post. In this case instead of having 'Value' column in MyTable, i have 6 different Value columns (Value_1, value_2...value_6). Each Value column has it's own distinct values (which can be similar between the columns. For example: Value_1 and Value_2 column can has the same values). If each column has a 50 distinct values, the expected result is a 450 columns. Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: I can use your query 6 times, each time on a different column, and then join the output tables. It would be smarter to use your query for 6 different columns in one time.

Comment: One more thing - I'm having trouble to insert the output into a table. I tried to use "select * into table" but it doesn't works.