# How to pivot dynamically with date as column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have a table with product id's and names, and another table with the stock of these products on certain dates. Such as `Item1` had `6` stock on `1-1-2014` and `8` stock on `2-1-2014`.
I'm trying to show these in a stored procedure so that it looks like a calendar, showing all the dates in a month and the stock available in the cells. What is the best way to show this?

**For example:**

```
Name  | 1-1-2014 | 2-1-2014 | 3-1-2014 | 4-1-2014
Item1 |     6    |     8    |          |    6
Item2 |          |     2    |     1    |
```

Original tables - Names

```
 ID |   Name 
  1 |  Item1
  2 |  Item2
```

Original tables - Stockdates

```
 ID | NameID  | Stock |    Date 
  1 |    1    |   8   |  2-1-2014    
  2 |    2    |   2   |  4-1-2014
```

Comment: Use a calendar table

Comment: Having dates as column names is incredibly poor table design.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your original tables, not just the expected output please?

Comment: Updated with the tables

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2014 management studio

Comment: @Barmar Having dates as column names IS poor table design but when we are talking about reports this is pretty common task. Databases are not supposed to be readable for humans but reports are.

Comment: @B0Andrew When I posted my comment, he hadn't added the original tables to the question. I thought that was the table, not the report.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is your sample table

```
SELECT * INTO #Names
FROM
(
SELECT 1 ID,'ITEM1' NAME 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ID,'ITEM2' NAME 
)TAB

SELECT * INTO #Stockdates
FROM
(      
SELECT 1 ID,1 NAMEID,8 STOCK,'2-1-2014 ' [DATE]
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ID,2 NAMEID,2 STOCK,'4-1-2014 ' [DATE]
)TAB
```

Put the join data to a temperory table

```
SELECT N.NAME,S.[DATE],S.STOCK 
INTO #TABLE
FROM #NAMES N
JOIN #Stockdates S ON N.ID=S.NAMEID
```

Get the columns for pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106) + ']', 
               '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 106) + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [DATE] FROM #TABLE) PV  
               ORDER BY [DATE]
```

Now pivot it

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '           
              SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT * FROM #TABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 SUM(STOCK)
                 FOR [DATE] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p      

            '     
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

And your result is here

[image]

Comment: Thats pretty cool and works thanks, just trying to plumb in my tables into it now. While testing I tried the 'SELECT * INTO #Names', where are these table names kept so I can remove them?

Comment: Its actually Hash table in Sql Server. It works like session(not in sense of time), it automatically gets destroyed when you close the tab where you are running query. If you want to drop table without closing it,just give DROP TABLE #Names @Craphex

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 - Fill the gaps (maybe not required)

If your stocks table does not contain stock from every day for every product then you have to get all the dates in a month from somewhere else. You can generate them with a recursive CTE: (variable declarations are omitted)

```
with dates as
(
   select @startdate as [date]
   union ALL
   select   [date] + 1 
   from dates
   where    [date] < @enddate
)
select  @strDays = COALESCE(@strDays + ', ['+ convert(varchar(8), [date],112) + ']', '['+ convert(varchar(8), [date],112) + ']') 
from    dates;
```

You can use your preferred date format but it's important to maintain it in all queries.

Step 2 - Bring data to a normal form. You can chose to store it in a temporary table or you can use a CTE again and combine this step with step 3.

Join `dates` (from above) with `products` (full) and with `stock` (left) so you obtain a table like this:

```
date
product_id    
items
```

For products and dates where stock is not available you display 0. `isnull` will do the trick. Make sure the `date` column is converted to `varchar` in the same format as in CTE above.

Step 3 - pivot the table (obtained at step 2) by `date` column in a dynamic query.

I can give you more details but not right now.
You can see something similar in another response:
[Spread distinct values over different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27040782/sprade-distinct-values-over-a-different-columns/27041265#27041265)