# SQL pivot query error: Unclosed quotation mark

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have 3 tables (1. Emp, 2. OnLeave,3.DaysWeeks). Im trying to write a pivot query that displyas empname, and calenderdates as columns)

Im getting following error, when I try to run the pivot query.

1.Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '2016-12-31])) as pvt'.

2.Incorrect syntax near '2016-12-31])) as pvt'

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME([CalDate]) 
                    FROM DaysWeeks
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SELECT @query = 
'WITH cte AS (
SELECT EmpDays.Employee,EmpDays.CalDate, ISNULL(v.VacationType,1) AS LeaveStatus
FROM dbo.OnLeave v
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT e.EmpID AS Employee, dw.CalDate AS CalDate, dw.DayOfWeekName AS DoWName
  FROM daysweeks dw,
      dbo.Emp e
      WHERE dw.CalYear = 2016 AND dw.monthnumber=1) AS EmpDays
ON
   v.EmpID = EmpDays.Employee
   AND v.StartingDate <= empdays.CalDate 
   AND v.EndingDate >= empdays.CalDate
)
SELECT * FROM cte PIVOT 
(Max(cte.LeaveStatus) FOR cte.CalDate in([' + @cols + '])) as pvt'


EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Comment: Simply try to print the value of `@query` and see if it is correct syntax. You can even manually execute contents of `@query` to see what are you missing

Comment: yes I tried to run, instead of @cols I passed a date then it is working fine. but my requirement is i need display all the dates of a month=1 needs to be displayed as columns.

Comment: Try removing [] from in query as the date are already enclosing in [date]. So your in would be in(' + @cols + ').  For more on this refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422109/how-to-pivot-dynamically-with-date-as-column

Comment: Thanks @J-D; I have one more questions i need filter the records by passing a deptId value (@deptId as smallint Select @deptId=1). But how can implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `QUOTENAME` is already added here

```
 STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME([CalDate])
```

You don't need `[` and `]` here,

```
 FOR cte.CalDate in([' + @cols + '])) as pvt'
```

which is wrong. It will make the entire pivot column list to consider as single column

Change it to

```
 FOR cte.CalDate in(' + @cols + ')) as pvt'
```

**Update:** To  filter the records by passing a `deptId` value (@deptId as smallint =1). Change your query like this

```
Declare @deptId SMALLINT = 1

......
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
 (SELECT e.EmpID AS Employee, dw.CalDate AS CalDate, dw.DayOfWeekName AS DoWName
  FROM daysweeks dw,
      dbo.Emp e
      WHERE dw.CalYear = 2016 
        AND dw.monthnumber=1 
        AND e.deptId = @deptId ) AS EmpDays
......

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query,N'@deptId SAMLLINT',@deptId = @deptId
```

Comment: Thanks @VR46. It is working now. But it is displaying all the dates from 1-1-2016 to 31-12-2016. But I need them for 1 month as I mentioned in the query as dw.monthnumber=1.

Comment: Yeah I got it now. the monthnumber condition I removed from @query but put on the top inside the cols. Now it is working fine. SELECT cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME([CalDate]) 
                    FROM DaysWeeks where monthnumber=1,

Comment: I have one more questions i need filter the records by passing a deptId value (@deptId as smallint =1). But how can implement it?

Comment: @Programmer2015 - Which table has `deptId` column

Comment: Emp table has deptId