# How to display transact SQL dynamic pivot result with PHP?

Tags: php, sql

Next to this question : [MSSQL 2012 : PIVOT typologies and dates using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887468/mssql-2012-pivot-typologies-and-dates-using-php) I have this result into Management Studio :

```
typo    01/04/2016 | 02/04/2016 | 04/04/2016 | 05/04/2016 | 06/04/2016 | 07/04/2016 | 08/04/2016 | 11/04/2016 |
TYPO1       0      |     0      |     0      |     0      |     0      |     0      |     0      |     0      |
TYPO2       13     |     0      |     29     |     30     |     24     |     18     |     17     |     22     |     
TYPO3       0      |     0      |     0      |     0      |     0      |     0      |     0      |     0      |     
TYPO4       6      |     1      |     12     |     16     |     17     |     6      |     18     |     11     |     
TYPO5       44     |     1      |     80     |     62     |     84     |     116    |     103    |     100    |
```

How can I display this result in PHP ? I start with :

```
$SQL = "
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX);

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 103) + ']', 
               '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 103) + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [DATE] FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(dateadd(S, [date_ticket], '1970-01-01') as date) AS [DATE] FROM [MyBase].[dbo].[ticket] WHERE date_ticket BETWEEN 1459461600 AND 1462053600) PV) PT
               ORDER BY [DATE];

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    typo_1,
    CAST(dateadd(S, [date_ticket], ''1970-01-01'') as date) AS [DATE]
FROM 
    [MyBase].[dbo].[ticket] 
WHERE 
    date_ticket BETWEEN 1459461600 AND 1462053600
) X
PIVOT (
    COUNT([DATE]) FOR [DATE] IN ('+@cols+')
) p';

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query;";

$result = sqlsrv_query($connexion, $SQL);
```

This result is based on April, and dates can change with choice of user (all the month or 3 days, etc.) ; so I would like to make an Excel export of this but how can I structure the output table ? Must I first do a loop on each column for each date ? Is there any way in PHP to copy this result table and paste it into Excel file ?

Comment: No body can help me ?

Comment: Up again, please :(