# Show Day Of Month in RDLC Report Columns based on month and year

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have a student Attendance table which Stores Student Record only if Student is absent. 
[image: Check Data in my attendance Table]

Now i wish this data to be displayed in a RDLC Report by automatically adding columns for all days of month and Status of All Students in a class. 
[image: Sample output where P stands for present and S stand for Sunday and A stand for Absent]

Comment: You need to use `PIVOT`. There are lot of questions and answer about it. Just search and you will be able to find an answer for your problem. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422109/how-to-pivot-dynamically-with-date-as-column

Comment: You need to supply the data for each data of the month. This would be the only reasonable approach. Once you have source data - then you need to use Matrix Table.