# SQL Server - Pivot two columns on a 3 column table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

i'm a bit stuck with SQL pivot, 
I have a 3 column table like this:

```
Name  Color  Date
TOM   BLUE   10-10-2018
MAT   RED    10-10-2018
TOM   BLUE   11-11-2018
```

And I want an output like this:

```
     10-10-2018  11-11-2018
 TOM  BLUE        BLUE
 MAT  RED
```

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question [How to pivot dynamically with date as column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422109/how-to-pivot-dynamically-with-date-as-column) with some tweeks for your case:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX);
SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 121) + ']', 
               '[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [DATE], 121) + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT [DATE] FROM tablename) PV  
               ORDER BY [DATE]

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '           
              SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT * FROM tablename
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(Color)
                 FOR [DATE] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p      

            '     
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query;
```

Comment: Hello Pedro, thank you for the answer, with your code I have 3 rows instead of two because the second register of Tom doesnt group in the first register. How could I do that?

Comment: Check if Tom you have extra spaces. I've created your scenario and worked perfectly: https://imgur.com/a/p3Evj

Comment: You were right Pedro, now it works perfectly! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do this :

```
SELECT *
FROM temp
PIVOT(
 MAX(Color)
  FOR [Date] IN ([10-10-2018], [11-11-2018])  
) PIV
ORDER BY Name DESC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ec28a/1)

IF you want to change NULL fields to empty, just use `ISNULL(ColName, '')`

LIKE THIS

```
SELECT PIV.Name, ISNULL(PIV.[10-10-2018],''), ISNULL(PIV.[11-11-2018],'')
FROM temp
PIVOT(
 MAX(Color)
  FOR [Date] IN ([10-10-2018], [11-11-2018])  
) PIV
ORDER BY Name DESC
```